# Asus F556U laptop Ethernet fails and Wifi unstable

Tags: networking, drivers, wifi, ethernet, asus

So I bought a pretty new laptop, and install linux on it, but the wired ethernet never works. It would load for a while, trying to connect, but eventually gives up. Wifi it would work for a while, then sometimes get disconnected, and then sometimes it works again. I know it should work because Windows 10 works fine.

I would really love to understand what is causing the problem. Can you explain the basic interaction between the ethernet card, drivers, and the os? If you can explain your basic network debugging technique (which commands to run, isolate the problem, etc...), that would be great!

Thx in advance!

Here is the output of ifconfig -a

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:4d:7b:be:95:d2  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:126 Base address:0x5000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1757 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1757 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:182772 (182.7 KB)  TX bytes:182772 (182.7 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:03:8c:07:a3:b7  
          inet addr:10.142.1.11  Bcast:10.142.3.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8d43:8f27:cebd:bb98/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2607:f140:400:a000:228c:f06a:9c42:ad60/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2607:f140:400:a000:682d:a784:54f3:f1be/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7026 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5138 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5916838 (5.9 MB)  TX bytes:1272641 (1.2 MB)
```

And here is ethtool eth0

```
     ~ $ ethtool eth0
    Settings for eth0:
    Cannot get device settings: No such device
    Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: No such device
    Cannot get message level: No such device
    Cannot get link status: No such device
    No data available

And here is sudo lshw -c network -sanitize
~ $ sudo lshw -c network -sanitize
[sudo] password for ***: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: [REMOVED]
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.043.02-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:126 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:ef204000-ef204fff memory:ef200000-ef203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 31
       serial: [REMOVED]
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.9.0-040900-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:130 memory:ef000000-ef1fffff
```

Comment: Normally ethernet should work out of the box. Did you try boot with some specific kernel parameters?

Comment: You should be using `ethtool enp2s0` and not `ethtool eth0` as there is no eth0 in iwconfig